# Programming a BLE Beacon to connect with server

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am developing a solution where, Fixed BLE beacon detects a moving BLE device and sends the relevant data to the server using wifi/ethernet/etc. All the examples I have found have BLE beacons talking to the mobile phone which in my case isnt true. AFIK an embedded systems engineer can configure the fixed beacon to send data to server. BUT is there any ready to use solution that lets the beacon connect to backend? Thanks.

Comment: Have the phone detect the beacon and be the one to report that fact to the server.  Going forward you'll need cooperating software on the phone anyway.

Comment: Chris, there's no phone involved in this set up.Just a BLE bracelet and fixed Beacon Scanner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention having a "[f]ixed BLE beacon [detect] a moving BLE device".  Understand that this is very different from the way an Apple-style BLE iBeacon works, which is a transmit only device.  (I mention this because the question is tagged with ibeacon.)

What you are describing is probably better described as either a beacon scanner or a BLE scanner.  My company has a [Raspberry Pi-based product](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/beacon-development-kit) that can scan for beacons and take programmatic action based on detections.  We have a [blog post](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/04/27/how-to-make-a-raspberry-pi-turn-on-a-lamp-with-an-ibeacon.html) about how to make a beacon turn on a lamp using this device, but you could just as easily make it contact a server when a BLE device is detected.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks @davidgyoung. Sorry, I had to add iBeacon as a tag since there were not too many tags available to indicate this was a BLE beacon related questions (hence, in my question i did used BLE beacon instead of iBeacon).

Comment: David, Since I have limited knowledge about Raspberry Pi, Can you please confirm if this can be used to communicate with server using wifi/ethernet?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.  I have done so myself.  A Raspberry Pi is just a little Linux computer.  You can send a message to a server using any high level programming language, or even do so on the command line with by typing something like: `curl --data '{"key":"value"}' http://myserver.com`

Comment: Thats a jackpot for me then. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @davidgyoung You are my hero of today. I've been Googling for an hour or so now trying to find out the exact possibilities/limitations of beacon devices, but with the technology being so new there is so little information out there (at least, information that isn't directly attached to a specific product).

Comment: @davidgyoung Also, just to make sure I understand: to communicate between a beacon and a server, over the internet, you need another device (with an internet connection) connected to the beacon either physically or through bluetooth? So with just a user device, a beacon and an internet connection (through WiFi) you would be missing the link between the beacon and the internet, correct?

Comment: You can either use an internet icon next wed beacon or you can use a mobile device that detects the beacon to call a web service.  Either or both architctures may be valid depending on your use case.